# Wrong Keyboard Layout For Java Application

Tags: java, windows, fonts, keyboard

My java application is not handling the keyboard input right under Windows 10. It works on other windows machines, even 10. What it's doing is adding +1 to each char. So if I type 1 it changes it to 2, a is changed to b. I have never seen anything like it. Does anybody know if this could be caused by a java setting?

Comment: A [mcve] would be most useful.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to explain it but whatever I type on the keyboard is changed to the next character. So I type 'b' and the input gets 'c'. It's across all characters. It seems like it shifted the ASCII table.

Comment: A [mcve] is source code of a short program that demonstrates the problem.  So far, we don’t even know if you’re using Swing, JavaFX, or something else.  We don’t know if you wrote your own control, or are seeing this behavior in a stock UI component.  How can we address the problem when we don’t know any of the circumstances under which it’s happening?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Note we might have been more help if you had followed the prompts as suggested by @VGR. I'd have been immediately suspicious of any custom fonts in cases involving character mapping problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out it was an issue with the Roboto font. Reinstalling the font has fixed the issue.